# How to convert List to a HashMap

Tags: java, hashmap, type-conversion

How can I convert this:

```
Map<String, Integer> itemsBought
```

So that I can add it on the ArrayList as Follows:

```
public void add(String prd, int qty){
        orderList.add(new Order(prd, qty));
}
```

Are there other solutions beside this:

```
hashMap.keySet().toArray(); 
hashMap.values().toArray();
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
for (Entry<String, Integer> entry : itemsBought.entrySet()) {
    orderList.add(new Order(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue()));
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
for (String product : itemsBought.keySet()) {
    int quantity = itemsBought.get(product);
    orderList.add(new Order(product, quantity));
}
```

I prefer more readability (not much though)

Comment: L Regardless of implementation, it is clearly demonstrated by Tarlog's answer that you must iterate the collection in order to populate the `ArrayList`. That being said, I don't see any value in this answer.

Comment: This solution does a map lookup for each key (which might be O(n) worst case, depending on implementation, looking at O(2n)). The first solution, again dependent on the implementation, might simply loop through all entries in O(n) total. For trivial map sizes this is completely irrelevant though.